# How can I sort which objects are shown to the developer in a .sqlproj file based on the Configuration of the project in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, configuration, sql-server-data-tools, sqlproj

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 to develop a SSDT project and I'm trying to sort which objects/scripts are shown to the developer in the IDE based on the Configuration that is chosen. This would allow me to manage files that have multiple configurations in which they are published.

//-----------------------

For example:

-If CONFIG_A is selected in the Configuration combobox, I'd like to make visible only the firstTable.sql script.

-If CONFIG_B is selected in the Configuration combobox, I'd like to make visible only the secondTable.sql script.

-If CONFIG_C is selected in the Configuration combobox, I’d like to make visible both firstTable.sql and secondTable.sql scripts.

//-----------------------

I'd like to make it as a real-time change to the Solution Manager, without having to reload the whole project, if possible.

Comment: Hi Rafael, can you expand a little on what you are trying to do - this is a bit of an unusual requirement! Why don't you want your developers to see all the files in the database?

Comment: I need that only the files that belong to a specific build are show to the developer so that the developer won't edit something that is not supposed to, sorting the relevant files to that build. Also, I have files with the same name but different contents that go to specific builds.